# Stuck between flex-end and space-between and margin

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-calc

In a flexbox, when I use `justify-content:space-between` the first and last items are exactly aligned to the bounds of flex container where space is divided between them. How can I align first item to the right where other items are also aligned to the right (not to entire the width)?

The sample code below is not good because when I use `flex-end`, **I have to set margin** for items and so the first one in each row **is not sticky to the right**.

```css
#flexcontainer{
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-justify-content: flex-end;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  background:#ff8800;
}


.flexitem{
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: flex;
 margin:20px;
 width:24%;
 background:#666666;
 box-sizing:border-box;
    height:50px;

}
```

```html
<div id="flexcontainer">
  <div class="flexitem"></div>
  <div class="flexitem"></div>
  <div class="flexitem"></div>
  <div class="flexitem"></div>
  <div class="flexitem"></div>
  <div class="flexitem"></div>
</div>
```

and this is not also good because items are not aligned to the right (but entire the width):

```css
#flexcontainer{
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background:#ff8800;

}


.flexitem{
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: flex;
 margin:0;
 width:24%;
 background:#888888;
 box-sizing:border-box;
    height:50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="flexcontainer">
    <div class="flexitem"></div>
    <div class="flexitem"></div>
    <div class="flexitem"></div>
  </div>
```

My desired output in image (first one sticks to the right with no margin-right and the 4th one sticks to the left if 4 element exist and others align to the right if more than 4):
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK the best you can achieve using a `flexbox` to achieve your desired output can be done manipulating the `flex-basis` and `margin` of the `flexitem`s using this:

```
  margin: 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex: 0 1 calc(25% - 40px);
```

1. The `flex-basis` of `calc(25% - 40px)` in the `flex` style divides the width into four adjusting for margin also.
2. Note I have set `flex-grow` disabled.
3. `flex-end` finishes it up.

Let me know your feedback. Thanks!

```css
#flexcontainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  background: #ff8800;
}
.flexitem {
  margin: 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex: 0 1 calc(25% - 40px);
  background: #666666;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="flexcontainer">
  <div class="flexitem"></div>
  <div class="flexitem"></div>
  <div class="flexitem"></div>
  <div class="flexitem"></div>
  <div class="flexitem"></div>
  <div class="flexitem"></div>
</div>
```

**EDIT**:

So I did some more adjustments to the margin calculations:

1. Change the `flex-basis` by reducing `10px` more to adjust for removing the 20px each at the left and right ends of a row:

   ```
   flex: 0 1 calc(25% - 30px);
   ```
2. For the rightmost / leftmost boxes to sit to the right / left edge:

   ```
   .flexitem:nth-child(4n) {
     margin-right: 0;
   }
   .flexitem:nth-child(4n + 1) {
     margin-left: 0;
   }
   .flexitem:last-child {
     margin-right: 0;
   }
   ```

Give me your feedback on this. Thanks!

```css
#flexcontainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  background: #ff8800;
}
.flexitem {
  margin: 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex: 0 1 calc(25% - 30px);
  background: #666666;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 50px;
}
.flexitem:nth-child(4n) {
  margin-right: 0;
}
.flexitem:nth-child(4n + 1) {
  margin-left: 0;
}
.flexitem:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="flexcontainer">
  <div class="flexitem"></div>
  <div class="flexitem"></div>
  <div class="flexitem"></div>
  <div class="flexitem"></div>
  <div class="flexitem"></div>
  <div class="flexitem"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. But I want the first one stick to the right (no margin) and if there are 4 items , the 4th one also stick to the left

Comment: @AliSheikhpour check it out now and let me know- I guess I have what you wanted...

Comment: Thank you. The key was to use of `nth-child`

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could simply remove the right margin in your first example, is this how you wanted it to look?

```css
#flexcontainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  background: #ff8800;
}


.flexitem {
  margin: 20px;
  margin-right: 0;
  width: 24%;
  background: #666666;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="flexcontainer">
  <div class="flexitem"></div>
  <div class="flexitem"></div>
  <div class="flexitem"></div>
  <div class="flexitem"></div>
  <div class="flexitem"></div>
  <div class="flexitem"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. This is very close to what I want except that left ones are not still sticky to the left. I added my favorite result to the question.